# SIGABRT while passing NSDictionary to UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, nsdictionary

In a UITableViewController subclass, i am unable load the data, i am fetching json data from Url,

**Json data:**

```
{
"terms": "a",
"results": {
    "Events": [
        {
            "Event_Name": "808 State",
            "Event_NavigateURL": "808-state"
        },
        {
            "Event_Name": "ASAP Rocky",
            "Event_NavigateURL": "asap-rocky"
        },
        {
            "Event_Name": "Abba Mania",
            "Event_NavigateURL": "abba-mania"
        },
        {
            "Event_Name": "Adam Ant",
            "Event_NavigateURL": "adam-ant"
        }
    ],
    "Sports": [
        {
            "SportsName": "Arsenal",
            "URL": "football/arsenal-tickets.htm",
            "SubCategory_NavigateURL": "football",
            "Event_NavigateURL": "arsenal",
            "type": "team"
        },
        {
            "SportsName": "Aston Villa",
            "URL": "football/aston-villa-tickets.htm",
            "SubCategory_NavigateURL": "football",
            "Event_NavigateURL": "aston-villa",
            "type": "team"
        },
        {
            "SportsName": "Fulham",
            "URL": "football/fulham-tickets.htm",
            "SubCategory_NavigateURL": "football",
            "Event_NavigateURL": "fulham",
            "type": "team"
        },
        {
            "SportsName": "Manchester City",
            "URL": "football/manchester-city-tickets.htm",
            "SubCategory_NavigateURL": "football",
            "Event_NavigateURL": "manchester-city",
            "type": "team"
        }
    ],
    "Venues": [
        {
            "Venue": "O2 Arena London",
            "Venue_LocationURL": "o2-arena-london",
            "Venue_City": "London",
            "Venue_Country": "United Kingdom",
            "Venue_CountryURL": "united-kingdom"
        },
        {
            "Venue": "The Odyssey Arena",
            "Venue_LocationURL": "the-odyssey-arena",
            "Venue_City": "Belfast",
            "Venue_Country": "United Kingdom",
            "Venue_CountryURL": "united-kingdom"
        },
        {
            "Venue": "Manchester Arena",
            "Venue_LocationURL": "manchester-arena",
            "Venue_City": "Manchester",
            "Venue_Country": "United Kingdom",
            "Venue_CountryURL": "united-kingdom"
        },
        {
            "Venue": "SECC Clyde Auditorium",
            "Venue_LocationURL": "secc-clyde-auditorium",
            "Venue_City": "Glasgow",
            "Venue_Country": "United Kingdom",
            "Venue_CountryURL": "united-kingdom"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Here is my code snippet,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{              
    return [dict count]; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewcellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text= [[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] valueForKey:@"Event_NavigateURL"];

    cell.detailtextLabel.text= [[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] valueForKey:@"type"];


    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     newViewController *obj=[[newViewController alloc]init];
     obj.str=[[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"SportsName"] valueForKey:@"Event_NavigateURL"] valueForKey:indexPath.row];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];

}
```

How is NSDictionary supposed to work with TableView?

What is the simplest way to get this done?

Comment: what error display in sigbart?

Comment: You would generally use a tableView with an array of NSDictionary objects and determine each dictionary in the array with indexPath.row. Do you have just one dictionary of data?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this

```
cell.textLabel.text= [[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] valueForKey:@"Event_NavigateURL"];

    cell.detailtextLabel.text= [[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] valueForKey:@"type"];

obj.str=[[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"SportsName"] valueForKey:@"Event_NavigateURL"] valueForKey:indexPath.row];
```

Use this ..

```
cell.textLabel.text= [[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Event_NavigateURL"];

    cell.detailtextLabel.text= [[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"];

obj.str=[[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SportsName"] ;
```

**UPDATED :**

Just update this code in your cellForRowIndex

```
      cell.textLabel.text= [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ , %@ ,%@ ",
 [[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Events"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Event_Name"] ,
 [[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SportsName"],
 [[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Venues"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Venue"] ];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but dude i want to display `Event_Name`,`SportsName`,`Venue` in my UITableView `cell.textLabel.text`..

Comment: @Krunal See my updated code. If you accept with my answer, just tick check mark.... Cheers :)

Comment: i do not want to display alternatively, i want to display all `Event_Name`, `SportsName` and all `Venue` together

Comment: All in one Label. How do I seperate string,? Using `,`? If you want to change format, just do it in `stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
 NSMutableArray *array=[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"];
```

here you'l get the array and use this array in tableview methods like below

```
NSString *str=[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey@"Event_NavigateURL"];

EDIT:-

    NSString *sportsName=[[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey@"SportsName"];
    NSString *Event_Name=[[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Events"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey@"Event_Name"];
    NSString *Venues=[[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Venues"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey@"Venue"];
```

Comment: ya i tried this, but dude i want to display `Event_Name`,`SportsName`,`Venue` in my UITableView `cell.textLabel.text`..

Comment: Dude i tried this, `eventsArr= [[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Events"] valueForKey:@"Event_Name"];
    sportsArr = [[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] valueForKey:@"SportsName" ];
    venuesArr = [[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Venues"]valueForKey:@"Venue"];
    [array addObjectsFromArray:eventsArr];
    [array addObjectsFromArray:sportsArr];
    [array addObjectsFromArray:venuesArr];` and i passed `array` to my tableView, but when i select 5th row it says `index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'`

Comment: because in that array there is only 4 objects but you are trying to get the 5th object that's why it shows an error.

Comment: which string should i display (sportsName , Event_Name or Venues) ? in `cell.textLabel.text`

Comment: based on your requirement you can select one of those.

Comment: for that you can add three labels for every cell and assign those values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29602/discussion-between-krunal-and-sunny)

Comment: @Krunal:Accept the answer which is useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your with this :

```
cell.textLabel.text= [[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Event_NavigateURL"];

cell.detailtextLabel.text= [[[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }
  id obj = [statuses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text =[[[obj valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"Sports"] valueForKey:@"Event_NavigateURL"];
  return cell;
}
```

Hope it could be help.